# how to specify controller and method names in Rspec controller test when using Devise-like route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

tl;dr: unable to rspec-test the devise controllers, help.

I am using Devise and have the following routes (default `devise_for` routes):

```
GET    /users/cancel(.:format)      devise/registrations#cancel
POST   /users(.:format)             devise/registrations#create
GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)     devise/registrations#new
GET    /users/edit(.:format)        devise/registrations#edit
PATCH  /users(.:format)             devise/registrations#update
PUT    /users(.:format)             devise/registrations#update
DELETE /users(.:format)             devise/registrations#destroy
```

I would like to test, using Rspec, that my controller method is spitting out the right output from a given set of parameters.

My spec file looks like this:

```
describe Users::RegistrationsController, type: 'controller' do
  it 'creates a user with given parameters' do

    post 'create', username: 'jonsnow', password: '012345678912345', authenticity_token: '12345'
    expect(response.status).to eq(200)
  end

end
```

The error I get is:

```
Failure/Error: post 'create', username: 'jonsnow', password: '012345678912345', authenticity_token: '12345'
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: 
No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users/registrations"}
```

It makes sense since I am using `devise_for` default routes and as you can see from the `rake routes` results, the correct route is `devise/registrations#create`, but I can't seem to find a way to specify the controller name to `devise/registrations`.  I think it's 'inflected' from the controller class name or something to `users/registrations`.  And I would preferably like to avoid messing with my routes in order to make my test successful.  How can I accomplish that?  (Please explain)  Thanks in advance.

My gem versions:

```
rspec '3.2.1'
ruby '2.1.5'
rails '4.2.0'
```

Comment: Not sure `Users::RegistrationsController` is correct? maybe `Devise`?

Comment: That's the name of the Devise::RegistrationsController subclass.  If I am testing my controller subclass shouldn't it be named after it?  I wouldn't be able to test my controller methods otherwise.

Comment: most would argue you wouldn't test this as there literally thousands of tests in the devise gem already to make sure this works.  https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/master/test/controllers

Comment: you would do an integration test to make sure you can actually login using something like capybara

Comment: @Anthony this doesn't help at all.  everything i read online is either incomplete or points me away from this simple action.  You're pointing out it may not be necessary to test it, but I don't understand how the developers insist on testing a controller independently to the route table but when testing for the controller response, which is what the controller is for in the first place, they force you to go back to routes but there's no way of explicitly saying which controller and action, everything seems to be inferred.  Is it me or that's just bad design?

Comment: @Anthony actually not using any view here so integration test with capybara doesn't work.  I tried with requests specs but I run into the same problem.  I don't know how to explicitly specify the controller and the action and inferred behavior is not conducive to this test.

Answer (score -3):

There is some additional configuration required to be able to test controllers that inherit from Devise.

```
describe YourControllerWhichInheritsDevise, type: 'controller' do
  before do
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
  end

  it 'creates a user with given parameters' do
    post 'create', username: 'jonsnow', password: '012345678912345', authenticity_token: '12345'
    expect(response.status).to eq(200)
  end
end
```

[From the Devise README](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise):
"If you are testing Devise internal controllers or a controller that inherits from Devise's, you need to tell Devise which mapping should be used before a request. This is necessary because Devise gets this information from the router, but since functional tests do not pass through the router, it needs to be stated explicitly."

Comment: I believe the documentation is misleading here, but what it meant is that you should add the devise mapping statement if you are using a devise model.  I came to this conclusion because I tested that line of code in my scenario and it didn't help.

Comment: please don't remove this post, it's for the community :)

Comment: Then I believe you have another issue, perhaps related to how you are namespacing your controller. I have done exactly what you are trying to do many times; I bet you'll find my above solution, while it might not fix whatever problem you're having currently, will still be required.